# When Form UI is changed programmatically, event handler won't fire for sure?

Tags: jquery, forms, event-handling

I realized that on a webpage, when a form's UI (checkbox, dropdown list, etc) is changed programmatically, the event handler (onchanged) is not fired?  Is this a standard rule -- that when a control is changed programmatically, the event handler will never get triggered?  Is there any exception?

Comment: That is correct, unless the code that changes the form field *also* explicitly triggers an event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is correct, unless as Pointy "pointed" out, you are also firing the event. In jQuery this is as easy as adding a call to [`.change()`](http://jqapi.com/#p=change) in your code that is changing the form.

Ex. -

Html:

```
<form id="aForm">
    <input></input><br />
    <input></input><br />
    <input type="checkbox"></input><br />
    <input type="checkbox"></input><br />
</form>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#aForm').change(function() {
   alert('Your form hath changed!');
})
$('#aForm').hide(function(){
   $(this).change();
});
```

jsFiddle working example - http://jsfiddle.net/qGLc2/